# create a histogram with plotly.graph_objs like in plotly.express

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, histogram

I'm doing visualization and I can create what I want in plotly express but I have to do it many times with different features so I prefer to use graph_objs to make subplots but I don't know how to create them.

`fig = px.histogram(eda, x="HeartDisease", color="Sex", barmode="group",  height=450, width = 450) fig.show()`

[image]

but when I try to do it in graph  `fig.add_trace(go.Histogram( x = eda['HeartDisease'], name=eda.Sex))`

error: The 'name' property is a string and must be specified as: - A string - A number that will be converted to a string

`fig.add_trace(go.Histogram( x = eda['HeartDisease'], color=eda.Sex))`

error: Bad property path: color

I hope you can help me!

the data

| Sex | HeartDisease |
| --- | --- |
| Male | HeartDisease |
| Female | Normal |
| Female | HeartDisease |
| Male | HeartDisease |
| Male | Normal |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no data presentation, I created a histogram with graph_objects based on the examples in the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/histograms/#specify-aggregation-function). instead of specifying a categorical variable as in express, we will deal with it by extracting the categorical variable.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = px.data.tips()

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(histfunc="count",
                           y=df.query('sex == "Female"')['total_bill'],
                           x=df.query('sex == "Female"')['day'],
                           name="Female")
             )
fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(histfunc="count",
                           y=df.query('sex == "Male"')['total_bill'],
                           x=df.query('sex == "Male"')['day'],
                           name="Male")
             )

fig.update_layout(xaxis_title='day', yaxis_title='Count', legend_title='sex')
fig.update_xaxes(categoryorder='array', categoryarray=["Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"])

fig.show()
```

[image]

**ploty.express version**

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.histogram(df, x="day", color='sex', barmode='group', category_orders=dict(day=["Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, Thank you for reply, I'm still trying to understand well, I add the table, I need to create it with only 2 features, Can you help me do it with 2 features because in your example you use "total_bill" and giving me a different result, thank you!

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer.